# Sleeping in a SwingWorker?

Tags: java, swing, sleep, swingworker

I need to feed test data to a Swing interval over a time period. The data set is long to parse, so I'm using a `SwingWorker` to parse it in the background. When it comes to feeding the data to the GUI (say, one item per second), I could start a `Timer` from the `SwingWorker`, but this seems overkill. Any reasons not to sleep from within the `SwingWorker` itself?

Cheers

Comment: I think you can sleep inside swingworker (you have own thread, so you can sleep in this thread) - I don't see any problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `SwingWorker` doesn't run on the EDT, sleeping within is perfectly fine.

> SwingWorker is designed for situations
>   where you need to have a long running
>   task run in a background thread and
>   provide updates to the UI either when
>   done, or while processing.

In my opinion, a `Timer` in addition to a `SwingWorker` would be overkill. Instead, just publish the parsed test data whenever possible, even at irregular intervals.

Answer (score 3):

While you make the SwingWorker sleep it will not be loading data.  If that is desired then this approach is fine.

If you want to keep loading the data and just pace the feeding to the GUI then it seems like a better design would be to start a Timer in the GUI that would check and pull new data from the worker at an interval, instead of the worker having to make `invokeLater` calls back to the GUI.

Comment: agreed from outside, because nothing guarenteed that SwingWorker ends before next Action from (any) Timer +1